# Address of DLL changes in Win XP SP3: CoreLan Exploit writing Tutorial part 1

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities, buffer-overflow, vulnerability, windows-xp

I was following the [CoreLan Exploit writing Tutorial Part 1](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/07/19/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-1-stack-based-overflows/).

OS used: Windows XP SP3

I tried to use “C:\Program Files\Easy RM to MP3 Converter\MSRMCcodec02.dll” for the instruction “jmp esp” [ff e4] but the address of the dll [and hence the instructions getting executed] changes in each run.

1. Why is this happening?
2. Someone suggested that this is caused by Rebasing of DLLs. I'm not sure hire this can be resolved. Can this be solved by changing the base address of the DLL?
3. How can I continue with the tutorial?

Comment: Windows [XP didn't have ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: @NeilSmithline, but [you can install it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2458544).

Comment: I haven't installed any ASLR package. Win XP SP 3 default system only

Comment: I got a suggestion that this may be due to rebasing of DLLs